# Facebook Authentitacion

Tags: facebook, api

I'm coding an API and trying implements the Facebook Auth. My scenery, I've *front-end* and the *back-end*, both in different domain. i.e:

**Front:**

```
http://myappfront.com
```

**Back:**

```
http://myapiback.com
```

The *Front* will authenticate with Javascript SDK and send to *Back* just the *User access Token*, and *Back* will validate this Token with PHP SDK.

My question is:

I need two apps on Facebook for each domain? The authentication will works with different APPs?

Comment: No, use one app - otherwise you will have all the problems that using different app ids brings with it (starting with getting different app-scoped user ids for one and the same person.) As long as you need to perform login only on the first domain, you should be fine. (Using the access token in the backend has nothing to do with the app domain settings.)